# Android RecyclerView DiffUtil.Callback: areContentsTheSame() and getChangePayload() giving different comparison results

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

There are 2 functions to override in DiffUtil.Callback:

```
areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)

getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)
```

I know the former checks if the content has changed, I'd like to simply compare if they are the same instance by directly using '==', because I trust my item will be a new instance when it gets updated. But the same comparison gives different result in the latter function.
Here's the code:

```
public class MyDiffUtilCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {
  List<App> mNewList;
  List<App> mOldList;

  public MyDiffUtilCallback(List<App> newList, List<App> oldList) {
    mNewList = newList;
    mOldList = oldList;
  }

  @Override
  public int getOldListSize() {
    return mOldList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getNewListSize() {
    return mNewList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    return mNewList.get(newItemPosition).id == mOldList.get(oldItemPosition).id;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    return mNewList.get(newItemPosition) == mOldList.get(oldItemPosition);
    // This always returns false correctly whenever the item gets an update, it's working as expected
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    if (mNewList.get(newItemPosition) == mOldList.get(oldItemPosition)) {
      return null; // But this is always being executed
    }
    return mNewList.get(newItemPosition).data; // This is never executed, why?
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the same comparison between the old item and the new item gives different results, does the super class modify the list or something?

Answer (score 0):

From Android [definition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.Callback#getchangepayload):

> When areItemsTheSame(int, int) returns true for two items and areContentsTheSame(int, int) returns false for them, DiffUtil calls this method to get a payload about the change.

You should try and change for a more details test, also I've found a nice article on [Medium](https://medium.com/tech-insider/diffutil-handling-recyclerview-smartly-ac3401d22903) that implement `getChangePayload`. I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in areItemsTheSame() I'm comparing item.id and In areContentsTheSame() and getChangePayload() I'm comparing the instance. I expect the result to be true, false, false, but I got true, false, true, I don't know why the latter 2 functions are returning different results, they are doing the same comparison.

Comment: Yes indeed, I mixed up the signature function my bad. Have you try in debug mode to see why it was always true in `getChangePayload` ? Also did you check the article in my post ?